# Bad hostname provided

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-passport

Passport Version: ^10.1

Laravel Version: 8.77.1

PHP Version: 8.0.9

Database Driver & Version: mysql 8.0.27

I can not get access token.
when I call it manual by curl it get this response.

this host name is generate inside the docker container

I'm test 192.168.224.6 ip of docker container but it also not work

```
/var/www/html # curl --location --request POST 'http://docker-nginx/oauth/token' \
> --header 'Accept: application/json' \
> --form 'grant_type="password"' \
> --form 'client_id="4"' \
> --form 'client_secret="hZJ33buLLIe3ekqe1dv62tn6RkBFMp59fZjeBgPW"' \
> --form 'username="creatrre@gmail.org"' \
> --form 'password="creatrre@gmail.com"' \
> --form 'scope=""'
{
    "message": "Bad hostname provided.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 391,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 332,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/app/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 97,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 51,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 172,
            "function": "handleException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustHosts.php",
            "line": 48,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustHosts",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 142,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 111,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/releases/20211223205412/public/index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
/var/www/html #
```

Comment: This usually happens to me when there is some badly defined function in the controller, such a missing curly brackets.

Comment: It seems that the closing curly bracket for `--form 'scope=""'` is missing.

Comment: maybe a backslash missing at the end on the line @hup is indicating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't use any prefix for passport, it is better to use

APP URL instead docker container name http://docker-nginx

http://docker-nginx/oauth/token        wrong

env('APP_URL')/oauth/token             correct